# I have a DetailsView in edit profile section. User should be able to edit his profile and save changes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am able to display data in the details view. When I click on 'edit' it lets me edit, but when I click on 'save' it does not get updated. Please refer to my code below. The user can only change mobile, address and email.

```
protected void UserDetailsView_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    TextBox mobile = (TextBox)UserDetailsView.Rows[4].Cells[1].Controls[0];
    TextBox email = (TextBox)UserDetailsView.Rows[5].Cells[1].Controls[0];
    TextBox address = (TextBox)UserDetailsView.Rows[6].Cells[1].Controls[0]; //as TextBox;

    CurrentUser.Employee.MobileNo = mobile.Text;
    CurrentUser.Employee.Email = email.Text;
    CurrentUser.Employee.Address = address.Text;

    DataBaseManager.UpdateEmployee(CurrentUser.Employee);

    UserDetailsView.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);

    UserDetailsView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Does record updates in database successfully? If I'm not mistaken you need to fetch data from database and bind it again.

Comment: Any error while debugging the code?

Comment: There is no error as such. Just that data  does not get updated. I have a bind function as well which i call upon pageload.

Comment: for Address it is saving "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox" in database.